# One part of the proof of equivalents metrics problem in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ and $(\mathbb{R}, d')$ two metrics spaces  so that for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ $$d(x,y)=|x-y|$$ $$d'(x,y)=|e^x-e^y|$$ For $\varepsilon>0$ the respective open balls are: $$B(x,\varepsilon)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}: |x-y|<\varepsilon\}$$ $$B'(x,r)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}: |e^x-e^y|<\varepsilon\}$$.

Show that for all $r>0$ exist $\delta>0$ so that $B'(x,\delta)\subseteq B(x,r)$.

Comment: The logarithm is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by Friedrich Philipp, you can use the continuity of the logarithm function $\log:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R$.

In particular, since $\log$ is continuous at the point $e^x\in\mathbb R_+$, given any $r>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|\log (e^x)-\log z|<r$ for every $z\in\mathbb R_+$ such that $|e^x-z|<\delta$.

Since $e:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_+$ is onto, we can write any $z\in\mathbb R_+$ as $z=e^y$. Thus we have,

$|\log(e^x)-\log(e^y)|=|x-y|<r$ whenever $|e^x-e^y|<\delta\Longrightarrow B'(x,\delta)\subseteq B(x,r)$ as desired.