# Let $d':\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ be the metric defined by $d'(x,y)=|e^x-e^y|$. Show that $d'$ is equivalent to the euclidian metric.

Tags: general-topology

I looked around and it doesn't seem this particular question was asked anywhere. The first part of the question was actually to prove $d'$ was a metric, but I've done that and it was easy enough. I don't understand how to prove it is equivalent to the euclidean metric, however.

Let $d$ be the euclidean metric. Then, for any $x,y\in\mathbb R$, $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. I understand that, given this definition for the euclidean metric, I need to prove the statements

$$
\forall x\in\mathbb R,\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0:\forall y\in\mathbb R,\quad|x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow|e^x-e^y|<\varepsilon
$$

and

$$
\forall x\in\mathbb R,\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0:\forall y\in\mathbb R,\quad|e^x-e^y|<\delta\Rightarrow|x-y|<\varepsilon.
$$

I'm having trouble getting my head around these particular calculations. Typically, these have some small trick that solves the calculation, so I'm probably missing something; is there any such hint someone could point out to me?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1690998/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2008518/42969.

Comment: If you are keen on an $\epsilon -\delta$ proof Mean Value Theorem for exponential and logarithm is a hint.

Comment: Thanks to both. I find it strange that the question didn't appear anywhere else, but apparently it was asked before. Do apologize for the duplicate.